# Static interface method

Tags: java, android

I have this design pattern:

```
interface IDriver {
   String getName();
}

class DriverX implements IDriver {
   @Override
   public String getName() { return "X"; }
}

class DriverY implements IDriver {
   @Override
   public String getName() { return "Y"; }
}

class DriverFactory {
   public IDriver getDriverByName(String name) {
       if (name.equals("X")) {
          return new DriverX();
       }
       if (name.equals("Y")) {
          return new DriverY();
       }
   }
}
```

What I want now, is make a list of driver names without having to instance them. Java 8 allows me to use `static` interface methods, but Java 7 doesn't. I cannot use Java 8 as my Android target is below API 24.

Is there a way to do this without having to instantiate the drivers?

Comment: You could put static final fields in your classes. Then you would have `if (name.equals(DriverX.NAME)) ...`

Comment: @khelwood would this be convention, or in the interface?

Comment: Your methods are all missing return types.

Comment: You can't specify anything static about the implementing classes in the interface, so it would be convention.

Comment: Even in Java 8, a static method on the interface isn't part of the interface's specification about implementing classes; it's just a static method that belongs to the interface.

Comment: "make a list of driver names" - what do you mean here? do you want to make a string array containing the result of getName() for every class that implements IDriver?

Comment: I think static interface methods are not even inherited, as opposed to static class methods.

Comment: @shmosel typo, i fixed it.

Comment: @GilMoshayof make a list of classes and call `getName()` to create a `String[]` of available driver names.

Comment: You might want to consider using an enum instead of isolated subclasses. At least for this simplistic example it could make sense. It gets less practical as the class complexity increases.

Comment: @shmosel Of course the drivers are much more complex. Some use Bluetooth, some USB, so I do need to have classes that implement an interface.

Comment: For the record, enums can implement an interface.